# How do I preform a script on an entire folder?

Tags: photoshop-script

I wrote a script that performs some adjustments, saves then closes the image:

```
preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;
imageWidth = activeDocument.width.as('px');
imageHeight = activeDocument.height.as('px')-30;
activeDocument.resizeCanvas(imageWidth,imageHeight,AnchorPosition.TOPCENTER);
app.activeDocument.save();
app.activeDocument.close();
```

Is there a way I can get this to run on a whole folder of images?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
#target photoshop
#strict on

main();
function main()
{
    var path = "/d/Images/";

    var inputFolder = new Folder(path );
    var inputFiles = inputFolder.getFiles("*.*");

    for(index in inputFiles)
    {
        // open the file
        var fileToOpen = new File(inputFiles[index]);
        open(fileToOpen);

        // do the processing
        preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;
        imageWidth = activeDocument.width.as('px');
        imageHeight = activeDocument.height.as('px')-30;
        activeDocument.resizeCanvas(imageWidth,imageHeight,AnchorPosition.TOPCENTER);
        app.activeDocument.save();
        app.activeDocument.close();

    }
}
```

I did not try, but it should work.
Hope it helps.